# How to use aggregated initialization in derived class with CRTP pattern?

Tags: c++, c++17, crtp

The standard that I use is `c++17`.

The problem is that I want to remake my code and reorganize the structure of my code with CRPT because it fits very well but the problem is that previous code uses aggregated initialization within classes like:

```
ClassWithNoParent get(const T_& unit) const {
        return {.w = 1,
                .h = 1,
                .c = 1,
                .n = 1};
    }
```

and it's fine. When I use CRTP

```
class DefaultClass {
 public:
    int n;
    int c;
    int h;
    int w;
};

template <class SuccessorT, class T = DefaultClass>
class BaseCRTPClass {
 public:
    int w;
    int h;
    int c;
    int n;

    SuccessorT get(const DefaultClass&) const {
        return   {.w = 1,
                  .h = 1,
                  .c = 1,
                  .n = 1};
    }
};

class Successor : public BaseCRTPClass<Successor> {};

int main(){
    Successor t;
    auto k = t.get(DefaultClass{});
}
```

The compilation fails with the error

```
21:25: error: could not convert '{1, 1, 1, 1}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Successor'
```

It's expected because standard wants `Successor` to be aggregated, however I am not quite sure that `c++17` strictly forbids to have no base class. It restricts constructor (as I understood, but I may be wrong). So, how could I get this problem bypass?

How can I keep aggregated initialization for the derived class that is defined by CRTP?

P.S. Why do I want to keep the aggregated initialization? Because many places in my code uses this initialization, but if will remake in CRTP, then everything will be crushed and I will be obliged to replace all aggregated initializations on some constructors...

Comment: Successor is an aggregate already. That's not where the problem comes from. I'm not sure exactly what to make of this, but have a look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7qf85o). Apparently specifying `SuccessorT` and removing the designated name for the first parameter makes the code compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to CRTP. Aggregate initialization of derived classes was only introduced in C++17. To aggregate-initialize a derived class, the base class must be initialized as the first item, in its own initializer list. So to get this working, use a double-brace:

```cpp
return {{.w = 1, .h = 1, .c = 1, .n = 1}};
```

To illustrate, say you have a simpler, non-template class:

```cpp
struct Base { int a; };
struct Derived : public Base { int b; };
```

You have to initialize `Base` as the first item:

```cpp
Derived x = { 
    { .a = 42 }, // Base
    .b = 24      // b
};
```

Comment: Designated member initializers is a C++20 feature, and is not part of the core C++17 language standard (but many compilers offer is as an extension).